# Create percentage out of given results in a query

Tags: php, laravel

I have a function which returns dataset of totalcount of items (y) and I need to make percentage out of this results. So I need

```
(y / SUM(y)) * 100)
```

One y over sum of all y's in resultset.

This is my function:

```
public function getVisitsByClients($filters = [])
    {

        $query = $this->filtersRepository->unionAllSources(function ($table) use ($filters) {
            return DB::connection('customer')->table($table)->selectRaw('visit_last_action_time, config_device_type');
        }, null, 'visit', $filters);

        $this->filterByDate($query, $filters);

        if ($query) {
            $totalSumQuery = DB::table(DB::raw("({$query->toSql()}) as visits"))->selectRaw('COUNT(*)');
            $result        = DB::connection('customer')
                ->table(DB::raw("({$query->toSql()}) as visits"))
                ->selectRaw("config_device_type name, COUNT(*) y, COUNT(*)/({$totalSumQuery->toSql()})*100 percentage")
                ->groupBy('config_device_type');

            return $result->get();
        } else {
            return [];
        }
    }
```

But when I run this I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031
```

Btw it works if I remove filter:

```
$this->filterByDate($query, $filters);
```

But I need this filter, it is an array of dates (start and end). Without filter I get wrong percentage because it is calculating the y / sum of all y's, not only in the given date frame.

**EDIT**

This is my `filterByDate` function:

```
private function filterByDate($query, $filters, $field = 'visit_last_action_time')
    {
        if (!empty($filters['start'])) {
            $query->where($field, '>=', $filters['start']);
        }
        if (!empty($filters['end'])) {
            $query->where($field, '<=', $filters['end']);
        }
    }
```

For example... If there is no filter I would have something like 55 / 12000 * 100, but if I choose date range between 2017-10-10 and 2017-10-20 I have 55 / 4000 * 100 ... And that's why I get wrong percentage.

Comment: Show your filterByDate function, since it works if you remove that line.

Comment: I've edited my question!

Comment: Depending on the format of your filters[start] and filters[end], is it possible you just need to use $query->whereDate rather than $query->where here?

Comment: if I `dd($query->toSql()` I get this: `"select visit_last_action_time, config_device_type from 'visit_1' where date('visit_last_action_time') >= ? and date('visit_last_action_time') <= ?"` ... this is using whereDate

Comment: I think it's probably because you're passing in the query twice manually, but only binding once, so the bindings aren't being updated. You might want to try a join instead.

Comment: I think a join would not be possible in this case since I get query in second table from the sql of the first query.
`->table(DB::raw("({$query->toSql()}) as visits"))`

Comment: You're right, you're querying a subquery directly. I cannot remember if you can pass the query into the table directly, but you definitely may want to rethink your approach here. Try writing out the sql and test it before converting it to QueryBuilder. And my initial assessment was close: you're passing in parameters with both queries using `toSql`, but it does not pass the values at all.